# rails fake data, considering switch from faker to forgery, any advantages or pitfalls?

Tags: testing, ruby, ruby-on-rails

With Ruby on Rails I've usually used **[Forgery](https://github.com/sevenwire/forgery)** for generating dummy data for testing.

I've noticed recently that several clients and tutorials are using **[Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker)**

They both seem fairly similar in use and popularity:
**Faker** 128 forks, 418 watchers.
**Forgery** 59 forks, 399 watchers.

They both seem similar in how current they are:
**Faker** Most updates are from 6 and 9 months ago.
**Forgery** Most updates are from 4 and 9 months ago.

The one distinguishing factor I've found so far is that **Forgery** seems like it has better instructions.

Are there any particular *benefits* or *disadvantages* to using one over the other?
Have you ever needed to switch from one to another for a particular reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Ffaker](http://rdoc.info/github/EmmanuelOga/ffaker/) so I guess that's one for the Faker camp - I found the API docs to be plenty sufficient, it's not like it's a hugely technical process, generating fake data.

Comment: any reason for using ffaker over faker?  Thx.

Comment: Did you click the link? >_>